# Radius of inner circles given radius of outer circle and number of inner circles in circular fractal

Tags: geometry, circles, fractals

I am trying to create a circular fractal in which each circle is composed by a given number $n$ of smaller circles.

It would look something like this for $n = 8$:
[image: (The smaller circles should touch each other, however)]

However, I don't know how to calculate the radius of the smaller circles.

Of course I know that the distance from the centre of the bigger circle to the centres of the smaller circles is $r_1 - r_2$, where $r_1$ is the radius of the bigger circle and $r_2$ is the radius of the smaller ones, and that their radius is $\frac{d}{2}$ where $d$ is the distance between two adjacent circles' s centres.

$d$ is for sure related to $n$ but I don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: Is $d$ the distance between small circle centers? Are inner circles touching? (In your diagram they are not).

Comment: @Narasimham yes, it is, and yes, they should touch, thanks for asking.

Comment: Are you trying to use an [Iterated Function System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) to create something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hT4up.png)?

Comment: @Mark McClure yes, but I've removed the outline and added a circle of radius `d - r2` in the centre, so it looks more like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JWcpQ.jpg).

Comment: @user6245072 So, the resulting fractal loses the "just touching" effect that the initiator had. Not surprising, as the limit set for the IFS is independent of the seed. Perhaps, it would make sense to think in terms of a so-called polygasket, as in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237964/sierpinski-triangle-for-other-polygons/1238221#1238221)?

Comment: @Mark McClure yes, but in this case we're not looking at polygons, or are we? It's just circles that create the illusion of a polygon.

Comment: @user6245072 The attractor of an IFS is uniquely determined by the IFS. The initial seed affects the appearance of the first few approximations but has no bearing on the final fractal itself. The [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your fractal is definitely a regular polygon.

Comment: @Mark McClure I don't think I am following the question anymore :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the triangle formed by the centers of two adjacent small circles and by the center of the outer circle; if the inner circles touch, then one has:
$$
(r_1-r_2)\sin{\pi\over n}=r_2.
$$
From that you can compute $r_2$:
$$
r_2=r_1{\sin(\pi/n)\over1+\sin(\pi/n)}.
$$

Comment: ....how? I never studied equations with monomials at the denominator, sorry. Could you solve it for me?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Crazy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works! And it's quite beautiful, I must say.